# redux-promise-middleware error handling without thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-promise-middleware

We are using redux-promise-middleware and having some difficulty working out what to do about error handling, all errors returned as 400 codes are just handled as 'FULFILLED'. I get that this is probably the correct behaviour but surely there is a way to catch an error in a promise in this setup. As we are not using redux-thunk, I am specifically asking how you would handle say a 400 error being returned from a promise.

our setup is very basic but I'm sure we should be able to

```
const export doSomething = object => {
 const promise = API.doSomething(object)
 return {
  type: "DO_SOMETHING",
  payload: {promise: promise}
 }
}
```

reducer

```
export default (state = initialstate, action) {
 switch(action.type){
  case "DO_SOMETHING_FULFILLED":
   return action.payload
  case "DO_SOMETHING_REJECTED":
   return console.log(action.payload)
  default:
   return initialstate
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to set payload to `{promise: promise}`
Just put the promise directly 
Try this for first

```js
export const doSomething = object => {
 return {
  type: "DO_SOMETHING",
  payload: API.doSomething(object)
 }
}
```

This is just a little decoration suggestion(not obligated)

```js
export const doSomething = object => ({
   type: "DO_SOMETHING",
   payload: API.doSomething(object)
})
```

Now the answer:
First of all you need check if API.doSomething(object) **throws** an Error
Or returns Promise.reject() on case of 400 respond code

If it doesn't you need to make it throw

```js
if(res.code === 400) {
  throw new Error()
}

// Or just use a library like axios
```

Promise doesn't know what happened inside you code,
in order to get to `DO_SOMETHING_REJECTED`
Is to make the `API.doSomething(object)` throw in 400